# Npgsql count rows error

Tags: count, npgsql

The code I have a problem with:

```
NpgsqlCommand if_ex = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT count(id_unit) FROM unit WHERE name=" + "'" + tmp + "'", conn);
      int ex = (int)if_ex.ExecuteScalar();
```

Throws an exception:

> Specified cast is not valid.

I am trying to get the row count of columns that have the same name (the string that I pass)

i know I should use parameters, but at this point I am only testing a few things so I figured might as well just do it like this for now.

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens because the return type of a query like: select count(*) is an long and not an int. If you change your code to long ex = (long)if_ex.ExecuteScalar(); you will get what you want. I hope it helps.